# Play selected music from spinner

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner set up with a list of songs and I'm trying to get the media player to play a song depending on which one has been chosen. I have set up the selected song as a variable but the mediaplayer is not seeing it. "R.raw.txt" is not seeing the string for some reason.

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (mp == null) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.text);
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try R.raw.txt instead of R.raw.text in creation of your media player.